# If !(condition) - try condition again after some time

Tags: c#

Sorry, couldn't think better title.

Basically, I want to try something an if, and if it is not, to try until it is.

```
CreateCall(list[i]);

if (!(call.CallState == CallState.Ringing || call.CallState == CallState.Error))
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
else
{ 
    i++; 
}
```

So I call method `CreateCall()` and I don't want to create next call until previous one have status `Error` or `Ringing`.

Comment: Sounds  like you need to await the result of a function.

Comment: What is a `call` object? Can you subscribe to any events it has rather than looping waiting for it to end?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a while statement:

```
while (!(call.CallState == CallState.Ringing || call.CallState == CallState.Error))
{ 
   Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is code like below

```
    int i=0;
    call=CreateCall(list[i]);
    while(i<list.count)
{
    if (!(call.CallState == CallState.Ringing || call.CallState == CallState.Error))
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
    else
    { 
        call = CreateCall(list[++i]); 
    }
}
```